# Python pivot table is returning nan value even though dataframe has no null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe in below given format:

```
ID_1 Code_M ID_2  Year     PI_code DI_code Sex No_of_PI No_of_DI Days_1 Days_2
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di100    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di200    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di300    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di400    2     1        1      100    100  
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di100    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di200    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di300    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di400    2     1        1      200    200
```

I'm running a pivot code on this dataframe but it's returning nan values below is code and it's output given, ideally output should be a single row with no Nan values

```
# Part 1 DI values
# pivot table to get the Di_code columns and values
di_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ,"Days_1","Days_2","Sex","PI_code"],
                        columns=["DI_code"],
                        values=["No_of_DI"])

di_pivot=di_pivot.reset_index()  
# Add new column names
cols=  ["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ,"Days_1","Days_2","Sex","PI_code"]
cols.extend([x for x in di_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1) if x != ''])
di_pivot.columns = cols
```

Output

```
ID_1 Code_M  ID_2  Year      Days_1  Days_2   Sex  di100 di200 di300 di400 
1     DM     100   2019-03   100     200       2    NaN  NaN    1    NaN
1     DM     100   2019-03   100     200       2    1    1      Nan   1
```

Comment: Output is expected, e.g `di100` is `NaN`, because not exist for columns `ID_1 Code_M  ID_2  Year      Days_1  Days_2, No_of_DI` with values `1     DM     100   2019-03   100     200, 100`. So pandas add not exist value `NaN`. similar for another combinations - if not exist added `NaN`s. So what is expected ouput from your sample data?

Comment: ID_1 Code_M  ID_2  Year       di100 di200 di300 di400 Sex Days_1 Days_2
1     DM          100   2019-03      1         1       1           1     2   100   100
This is the output I'm trying to achieve

Comment: So need no pivot? Only filyer first row? Not understand.

Comment: Actually I need solution for this requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912708/creating-dataframe-in-python-based-on-user-requirement and I used code given in this question can you please suggest something I need it urgently

Comment: Not understand, sorry.

Comment: Please provide the exact sample dataframe and the expected output. With the given dataframe the code gets back a different output you copied here.